# Temp and Undo in Cloned RMAN database are not changing according to the new database

Tags: database, oracle, rman, oracle19c

I cloned a Database using RMAN from one to Another. The clone was successful but the issue is that the temp file and location of tempfile is not changing according to the new database. Same is the issue happening with Undo datafile. What is the resolution for this ?
Below are the lines that I used for Backup and Clone respectively:

Backup:

```
connect target /;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK;
configure device type disk parallelism 5;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK BACKUP TYPE TO COMPRESSED BACKUPSET;
CONFIGURE channel 1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/bkpset_%U';
CONFIGURE channel 2 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/bkpset_%U';
CONFIGURE channel 3 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/bkpset_%U';
CONFIGURE channel 4 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/bkpset_%U';
CONFIGURE channel 5 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/bkpset_%U';
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/%F';
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_14072020/snapc_EB20AUX_14072020.f';
backup database include current controlfile ;
alter database open;
```

Restore:

```
connect auxiliary sys/sysmanager@EB20ST
duplicate database to EB20ST
db_file_name_convert='/eb20/EB20AUX/data01','/eb20/EB20ST/data01'
logfile
group 1 ('/eb20/EB20ST/redo01/redo01.rdo','/eb20/EB20ST/redo01/redo02.rdo') SIZE 256M reuse,
group 2 ('/eb20/EB20ST/redo01/redo03.rdo','/eb20/EB20ST/redo01/redo04.rdo') SIZE 256M reuse
backup location '/eb20/RMAN/EB20AUX_<DATE>' nofilenamecheck;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I see `db_file_name_convert='/eb20/EB20AUX/data01','/eb20/EB20ST/data01'.  Are you sure that your tempfiles also located in` /eb20/EB20AUX/data01`?
If not you need to add a pair of paths for tempfiles:

```
db_file_name_convert='/eb20/EB20AUX/data01','/eb20/EB20ST/data01','path_to_old_tempfiles_dir','/path_to_new_tempfiles_dir'
```

Comment: Yeah. I also researched some places and found the same thing as you're suggesting. Haven't got a chance to try this yet but hope it will resolve the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.